# How to reorder a pdf document with iText 7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm learning the iText 7 library and I want it for two main functions: reordering pages and rotating pages. The latter was pretty easy to figure out as its in the quickstart guides. The former I'm having some trouble with as all the examples I can find are either old or for java (or both).

I'm currently just trying to set up an example of moving the first page after the second page:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FILE_READ_LOCATION);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(FILE_WRITE_LOCATION);
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

PdfPage pageToMove = document.GetPage(1);

document.AddPage(3, pageToMove);
document.RemovePage(pageToMove);

document.Close();
```

For some reason, `document.Close();` throws a `NullReferenceException` (yet I don't see anything that's `null`). Any suggestions?

Here is what I've attempted for the `copyTo` or `CopyPagesTo` methods (`dest.Close();` throws an exception saying `Document has no pages`):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FILE_READ_LOCATION);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(FILE_WRITE_LOCATION);

PdfDocument src = new PdfDocument(reader);
PdfDocument dest = new PdfDocument(writer);

src.GetPage(1).CopyTo(dest);
src.CopyPagesTo(new List<int>(1), dest);

src.Close();
dest.Close();
```

Comment: `new List<int>(1)` creates an **empty list** with a **capacity of 1**. You might want to do `new List<int> { 1 }` (with curly braces) which creates a list with one entry, a `1`.

Comment: @mkl Oh, stupid move on my part. That seems to work. Now any suggestions for `src.GetPage(1).CopyTo(dest);` ?

Comment: `src.GetPage(1).CopyTo(dest)` copies the page *data* from the source to the destination, it merely does not yet add it to the destination page tree. This is why `CopyTo` returns a page object which you can use with `dest.AddPage(...)`; this allows you to insert the page at any position desired.

Comment: @mkl Interesting. So I guess this would be the proper way to do it: `dest.AddPage(src.GetPage(1).CopyTo(dest));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the FAQ entry [How to reorder pages in an existing PDF file?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/manipulating-existing-pdfs/itext7-how-reorder-pages-existing-pdf-file)

First you need to create a `List` of Integers. For instance:

```
List<int> pages = new List<int>();
pages.Add(2);
pages.Add(1);
for (int i = 3; i <= total; i++) {
    pages.Add(i);
}
```

Then you can copy the pages of one PDF to another PDF using this page sequence:

```
srcDoc.CopyPagesTo(pages, resultDoc);
```

Where `srcDoc` is a `PdfDocument` created using the `PdfReader` object, and `resultDoc` is a `PdfDocument` created using the `PdfWriter` object.

Comment: That is an example for java. Also, the `PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo` and `PdfPage.CopyTo` methods don't seem to do anything in C# (unless I'm using them wrong). After using those, the "`resultDoc`" still has 0 pages

Comment: This solution appears to drop document level meta data (unless one copies them manually) while the iText 5 version using `PdfReader.selectPages` and `PdfStamper` automatically keeps them. Shouldn't there be a solution keeping all the document level data?

Comment: @derekantrican *"(unless I'm using them wrong)"* - to allow us to check that you should show how you are using them. In particular, are your source document and target document different?

Comment: @mkl I've tried source and dest as the same `PdfDocument` and also as different documents. In both instances, I haven't figured out how to successfully use the `CopyPagesTo` or `CopyTo` methods

Comment: @derekantrican *"I've tried source and dest as the same `PdfDocument`"* - this is unlikely to work. *"and also as different documents"* - this should work. Please share your code to allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: @mkl I've updated my question with the requested code

Answer (score 2):

As @Bruno indicated, one can easily reorder a pdf document with iText 7 using an overload of the `PdfDocument` method `CopyPagesTo`.

Concerning your attempts

- `src.GetPage(1).CopyTo(dest);`

  `CopyTo(dest)` copies the page **data** from the source to the destination, it merely does **not** yet add it to the destination **page tree**. This is why `CopyTo` returns a page object which you can use with a `dest.AddPage(...)` overload; this in particular allows you to insert the page at any position desired.
- `src.CopyPagesTo(new List<int>(1), dest);`

  `new List<int>(1)` creates an **empty list** with a **capacity of 1**. You might want to do `new List<int> { 1 }` (with curly braces) which creates a list with one entry, a `1`.